# One to many database design problem

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to create a database table for my game, and would like to see what is the best approach.

I have lots of monsters, each monster has number of attacks, monsters do not necessarily have the same attacks.

Each monster has different hp, mp and other stats.

Each monster attack has power and speed and other stats.

Can anyone please help me design this table?

I am using MySQL for my database.

Comment: This is a database design problem and is not really specific to game development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables required: MONSTER, MONSTER_ATTACKS.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS MONSTER_GAME;
CREATE DATABASE MONSTER_GAME;
USE MONSTER_GAME;
CREATE TABLE MONSTER (
      id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      hp VARCHAR(64),
      mp VARCHAR(64),
      stats1 VARCHAR(64)
    ) TYPE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE MONSTER_ATTACKS (
      id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      monster_id INT,
      power INT,
      speed INT,
      Foreign Key (monster_id) references MONSTER(id)
    ) TYPE=innodb;
```

The important parts: MONSTER has a primary key of id, MONSTER_ATTACKS has a foreign key of monster_id that refers back to MONSTER's id.

Comment: I would do that, but wouldnt that make the database huge, and maybe lag the game ?

Comment: How would it make the database huge? Anyway, MySQL fares quite well with large numbers of records, provided you've got indexing and caching as appropriate, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: am sorry i meant the MOSTER_ATTACKS table, but you are right.

Comment: @saadlulu - what did you have in mind that would make the database not huge? It's up to you what you store in the MONSTER and MONSTER_ATTACK tables. If you're going to go with a database like MySQL, don't worry about the size - you've already encountered the main overhead.

Comment: @pete855217 I dont have anything else in mind, I was checking if there is any other way around this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having one table for the monsters, for example:

```
monsters
----------
monster_id
monster_hp
monster_mp
```

Then have an other table with the monster attacks, which is linked to the previous table by monster_id:

```
attacks
----------
attack_id
attack_monster #This field links to the monster_id field of other table
attack_power
attack_speed
```

Of course, you'll probably have more fields in there, but you get the idea.